# should I use PHP to connect my android app to mySQL db

Tags: android, mysql

I want to connect my android application to an external mySQL database and I found that I have to use web service to achieve that using php code. 
but I used to use java, Is there in java any equivalent to php code??

Comment: Use your favourite search engine and look for "Java MySQL tutorials" - this is not the place to ask this kind of question - read the FAQs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how the server side is implemented. Both php and java can implement the server side code and access MYSQL DB. Through your android client you dont' have to be concerned about the server side (If the server is not yours and just responds to your queries) , you have to make HTTP request POST or GET to achieve it.

Comment: so in the server side I can write in JSP and got the same result as PHP right?